# Specify & fetch Integer value in Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

How can I get my enum to contain numbers for string descriptions? I have used [Description] for text strings. I want something like

```
  Apple pie=1
  Strawberry pie=2
```

My database would carry the numeric fields & I will fetch text description from the enum. This does not work

```
public enum Pies
    {
        [Description("Apple pie")]
        "1"=1,
        [Description("Strawberry pie")]
        "0"=0
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, declare a valid enum:

```
public enum Pies
{
    [Description("Apple pie")]
    Apple =1,
    [Description("Strawberry pie")]
    Strawberry=0
}
```

You can use [reflection to access the `DescriptionAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695730/how-to-access-the-description-attribute-on-either-a-property-or-a-const-in-c#).

Comment: Thanks,I am successul in accessing the description, I just want to know how to include numeric fields instead of Apple & strawberry in the enum as the database would return me numbers & by using them I need to fetch the text description. Say if user selects Apple Pie in my dropdown I need to have 1 as its value.

Comment: @DamienJoe - How are you populating the dropdown? If you set the _value_ of the field to the enum value, you just need to _cast_ `(Pies)1`, for example.