# C# enum how to check if a description exists in the enum

Tags: c#, enums

I wonder if there is a method to check if the value is the description of an Enum.
I know

```
     Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EnumEntity),value)
```

could be used to check if the value is in the Enum, but how about the description?

For example,

```
 public enum LicenseTypes 
{
    [Description("A License")]
    A,
    [Description("B License")]
    B,
    [Description("C License")]
    C
}
```

Is there a way to check "A License" is a description of enum LicenseTypes?

Comment: Do you want to check A License is a description on any of they enums or just the enum A.

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695730/how-to-access-the-description-attribute-on-either-a-property-or-a-const-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would go something like this (untested):

```
bool isPresent = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LicenseTypes))
                     .Select(e => e.GetDescription())
                     .Contains("A License");
```

where GetDescrtiption() is the helper function defined in answer to this question:
[Get the Enum<T> value Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297299/get-the-enumt-value-description?rq=1)